# How to listen to changes for TextField using Provider package?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm re-writing a very simple app which calculates averages, however I have a hard time with a Provider package. I'd like to move the business logic out of files which are responsible for Widget creation. I'd like to use the Provider package.

Ok, I have the file responsible for building the layout, but I'd like to listen to changes in a TextField widget. How do I do it efficiently? I have another file, which is a provider class, it will listen to changes on this TextField widget. However, I do not want to to create ChangeNotifierProvider in the main.dart file, because I want a local state. I want to pass the value of the TextField to provider class.

Here's how my app looks like: 
[image: App]

### Code:

#### Layout:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../providers/arithmetic_average.dart';

class ArithmeticAverageScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ArithmeticAverageScreenState createState() => _ArithmeticAverageScreenState();
}


class _ArithmeticAverageScreenState extends State<ArithmeticAverageScreen> {

  final _textFieldController = TextEditingController();

  var _grades = List<Widget>();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _textFieldController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (context) => ArithmeticAverageProvider(),
          child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('arithmetic_average_title').tr(),
        ),
        body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              Card(
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      ListTile(
                        leading: Icon(Icons.help),
                        title: Text('arithmetic_average_help').tr(),
                        subtitle: Text('arithmetic_average_help_content').tr(),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ) 
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 16.0),
              Card(
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0, horizontal: 20.0),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text('arithmetic_average_your_grades', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5).tr(),
                      SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                      Text('arithmetic_average_grades_one_at_a_time', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,).tr(),
                      SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                      Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            width: 60.0,
                            child: TextField(
                              controller: _textFieldController,
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(
                                decimal: true
                              ),
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                hintText: '5',
                                labelText: 'arithmetic_average_grade'.tr()
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(width: 20.0,),
                          RaisedButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                            },
                            color: Colors.teal[300],
                            textColor: Colors.white,
                            child: Text('arithmetic_average_add_button').tr(),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 16.0,),
                      Wrap(
                        children: _grades,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

#### Provider:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ArithmeticAverageProvider extends ChangeNotifier {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

TextField "onChange" should call a method in "ArithmeticAverageProvider()" which calls "NotifyListeners()".

Comment: But I'd like a RaisedButton to retrieve a value from TextEditingController. How do I do it?

Comment: The onPress of the raised button, get the value from the textedit, update the value in ArithmeticAverageProvider() which do a NotifyListeners(). In the build you make a new widgets which takes the value from ArithmeticAverageProvider().